# Сохранить позицию элемента

Tags: javascript, html, position

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть страница с перетаскиванием элемента.

```js
(function(){
var elY, elX, obj, zIn=5, d;
d=document;
d.onmousedown=press;
d.onmouseup=release;
function press(ev){
if(ev){//остальные
obj=ev.target;//элемент который "взяли"
//если у элемента есть ИД с таким префиксом
if(obj.id.indexOf("DnD_el")==0){
d.onmousemove=elemMove;
elX=ev.clientX-obj.offsetLeft;
elY=ev.clientY-obj.offsetTop;}}
else{//IE
obj=event.srcElement;
if(obj.id.indexOf("DnD_el")==0){
d.onmousemove=elemMove;
elY=event.offsetY;
elX=event.offsetX;}};
//зет индекс позволяет любой элемент всегда иметь поверху всех, для этого в переменную нужно изначально занести число не менее общего количества всех перемещаемых элементов
obj.style.zIndex=zIn++;
return false;
 };//
//
function elemMove(ev){
var y, x;
if(ev){x=ev.clientX; y=ev.clientY;}//остальные
else{
x=event.clientX+(d.documentElement.scrollLeft||d.body.scrollLeft);
y=event.clientY+(d.documentElement.scrollTop||d.body.scrollTop);};//ИЕ
obj.style.left=x-elX+'px';
obj.style.top=y-elY+'px';
d.getElementById("coord").innerHTML=(y-elY)+' '+(x-elX);
return false;
 };//
//
function release(){d.onmousemove=null;};
 })();//
```

```html
<html><head>
<title>Перетаскиваем элементы.</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1251">
</head>
<body>
<div id="DnD_el4" style="position:absolute; cursor:move; padding:5px;">голый текст, берём,<br>и тоже тащим</div>
<button>
Сохранить
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Нужно сохранить позицию элемента после перетаскивания.

Comment: если после перезагрузки страницы то localStorage

Comment: Можете написать код?

Comment: Да, конечно напишу

Answer (score 0):

Результат: https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/vzoaYV?editors=1010

```js
(function(){

  console.log(localStorage.getItem('x'))
var saveX, saveY
var elY = localStorage.getItem('y') || window.innerHeight / 2
, elX = localStorage.getItem('x') || window.innerWidth / 2
, obj = document.querySelector('#DnD_el4')
, zIn=5, d;

obj.style.left=elX+'px';
obj.style.top=elY+'px';

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
  console.log(saveX, saveY)

  localStorage.setItem('x', saveX)
  localStorage.setItem('y', saveY)
}

d=document;
d.onmousedown=press;
d.onmouseup=release;
function press(ev){
if(ev){//остальные
obj=ev.target;//элемент который "взяли"
//если у элемента есть ИД с таким префиксом
if(obj.id.indexOf("DnD_el")==0){
d.onmousemove=elemMove;
elX=ev.clientX-obj.offsetLeft;
elY=ev.clientY-obj.offsetTop;}}
else{//IE
obj=event.srcElement;
if(obj.id.indexOf("DnD_el")==0){
d.onmousemove=elemMove;
elY=event.offsetY;
elX=event.offsetX;}};
//зет индекс позволяет любой элемент всегда иметь поверху всех, для этого в переменную нужно изначально занести число не менее общего количества всех перемещаемых элементов
obj.style.zIndex=zIn++;
return false;
 };//
//
function elemMove(ev){
if(ev){saveX=ev.clientX; saveY=ev.clientY;}//остальные
else{
saveX=event.clientX+(d.documentElement.scrollLeft||d.body.scrollLeft);
saveY=event.clientY+(d.documentElement.scrollTop||d.body.scrollTop);};//ИЕ
obj.style.left=saveX-elX+'px';
obj.style.top=saveY-elY+'px';
d.getElementById("coord").innerHTML=(saveY-elY)+' '+(saveX-elX);
return false;
 };//
//
function release(){d.onmousemove=null;};
 })();//
```

```html
<html><head>
<title>Перетаскиваем элементы.</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1251">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="coord"></div>
<div id="DnD_el4" style="position:absolute; cursor:move; padding:5px;">голый текст, берём,<br>и тоже тащим</div>
<button>
Сохранить
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, проверю.